# How to get an array of numbers from a sentence-style string in vanilla javascript and/or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have the following string or one like it:

```
var sentence = "Hey, I got 3 apples today from the 2 food stalls I was told about by 4chan. I'll give you one in a minute or 20."
```

and I want the following array from it:

```
var num_array = some_magic_function(sentence); // Contains: {3, 2, 4, 20}
```

I was looking at splitting by spaces, but that won't get numbers blended in. I can't do number by number because if a number has multiple digits, that's a problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a regex to handle this.

```
var num_array = sentence.match(/\d+/g).map(Number)
```